# Base64 image is not showing up in iOS email app

Tags: ios, email, base64, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am using a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) program that allows to customize email notifications, in a very limited way. It only allows me to create an HTML file and I cannot add attachments.

I need the template to have images, so my only solutions is to use embedded Base64 images. It works OK when I test and I can see the emails in the message in Outlook, but not on my iPhone. On my iPhone I get a button with "tap to download". When I click it, it shows a document with a cryptic name and when I click that document it opens my sharing options on the iPhone.

So, it does not display the image, and what is worse, is that it does not display the ALT text, so it looks ugly.

I tried all the suggested solutions I found on Stack Overflow - but none of them worked:

- I can’t use cid images, because I can't have attachments.
- Adding dimensions to an image does not work
- adding data-src or data-src-ng does not work
- adding img-src 'self' data:; to <meta http-equiv ... > does not work

How can I fix this?

Comment: "Outlook" as in desktop version of Outlook? Or the web version? Because embedded base64 images do not work in the desktop version of Outlook either - Word cannot render them correctly.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are seeing this issue in the web add-in or are you unable to see the image being rendered in the email in Outlook iOS app?